# KNN only predicting one class. Using python and sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, knn

I have a program that works flawlessly on known data sets such as the Breast Cancer Wisconsin data. I have created a novel data set with current air pressure in 100 cities and the future movement of a stock price. So about 100 dimensions plus the classifier which is -1 or 1. There are about 350 instances of data. The algorithm is showing about an 80% accuracy.

My problem is that when I input old data to make a prediction, it is only predicting 1, never -1. This is even the case when the training data contained the -1 classifier. Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KNN takes a vote on the n nearest neighbours. So with n=5 you need 3 neighbours to vote -1. This may be never if -1 is a rare occurrence and the -1s are not clustered together. Suggest you try other algorithms as well.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense :)